# How to get value as float from Combo box in c#

Tags: c#

Please help me in this situation

```
float sumofgradeintocradit = float.Parse(comboBox1.Text);
```

But an exception caught say "Input string was not in a correct format."

What is the problem please give me some solution I want to take an value from a combo box and store as an float .

Comment: Could you post the Content/HTML of the combobox because it sounds like .Text doesn't contain a valid float.

Comment: Side note, `sumofgradeintocradit` should be `sumofgradeintocredit`?

Comment: You could use `float.TryParse()` to see if the combobox text is a valid float value

Comment: restrict typing wrong decimal separator or replace it before parsing

Comment: Please show me how ??

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to convert display text back into a float,
you can use a custom object, which allows holding values separate from the shown text.

Example:

```
private class ComboItem
{
    public string ItemText  { get; set; }
    public float  ItemFloat { get; set; }

    public ComboItem(string itemText, float itemFloat)
    {
        this.ItemText  = itemText;
        this.ItemFloat = itemFloat;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.ItemText;
    }
}

private void AddItemsToComboBox
{
    comboBox1.Items.Add(new ComboItem("One Point Two", 1.2f));
    comboBox1.Items.Add(new ComboItem("Three Point Four", 3.4f));
}

private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var selectedFloat = ((ComboItem)comboBox1.SelectedItem).ItemFloat;
    Debug.Print("Selected: " + selectedFloat);
}
```

This also works for other things like the ListView.

Answer (score 0):

comboBox1.Text does not contain a flot in the right format.

For debugging Print / trace the value to confirm it.

You can add a client side validation to make sure it is in the right format.

After that if it is a client server app you can add a server side validation to handle the exceptions mentioned in the following MSDN and reprompt the user for input by using try parse or try catch.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2thct5cb(v=vs.110).aspx

Reference:
Also see the following on parsing numeric strings
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xbtzcc4w(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would try this:

```
float sumofgradeintocradit ;
if (float.TryParse(comboBox1.Text, out _))
    sumofgradeintocradit = float.Parse(comboBox1.Text);
```

This checks to see if the combobox1.text is a valid float, and if so, it assigns the value to `sumofgradeintocradit`

HTH

Comment: Thanks but it just say it's true or false and it show 0 but i select 1 or 2 in combo box.

Comment: What just says its true or false? Also are you making sure that you have `out sumofgradeintocradit` as the second parameter?